# HTML detect change on style of element

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know if there is a way to detect if some style, embedded into the html, has changed, for example:

```
<div id="corps" style="display: block;">
```

Is there an event that detects when "display" changes? (Javascript, not Jquery or something else)
The WC documentation is not very clear about what is detected by events (like "onchange" for example)

Comment: "change" events are only fired for `<input>` and other interactive form elements.

Comment: The MutationObserver does it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: this might help https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-tracking-changes-in-the-dom-using-mutationobserver-86adc7446401

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var ele = document.getElementById('corps');
    if (ele.style.display == 'block')
        ele.style.display = 'none';
    else
        ele.style.display = 'block';
});


var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for (var mutation of mutationsList){
        console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
    }
});
observer.observe(document.getElementById('corps'), { attributes: true});
```

```html
<div id="corps" style="display: block;">1111111111111111</div>
<button>Change div style</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `MutationObserver` and watch for attribute changes on specific element and check if the `style` is changed and your specific property in this case `display`.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div')
let display = div.style.display

var observer = new MutationObserver((mutations, _) => {
  for (mutation of mutations) {
    const {type, attributeName} = mutation;
    if (type == 'attributes' && attributeName == 'style') {
      let newDisplay = div.style.display;
      if (display != newDisplay) {
        display = newDisplay;
        console.log(`Changed to: ${newDisplay}`)
      }
    }
  }
});

observer.observe(div, {
  attributes: true
})

setTimeout(() => {
  div.style.display = 'flex'
}, 1000)

setTimeout(() => {
  div.style.display = 'block'
}, 2000)
```

```html
<div id="corps" style="display: block;">Observe</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `MutationObserver` to watch for changes to the `style` attribute, then check if the `display` property has changed.

Something like this might work:

```js
let currentStyle = myDiv.style.display;
console.log("Initial display: ", currentStyle);

let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(m) {
    if (myDiv.style.display != currentStyle) {
      console.log("Display changed to: ", myDiv.style.display);
    }
  });
});

let target = document.getElementById("myDiv");
observer.observe(target, {
  attributes: true,
  attributeFilter: ['style']
});

myDiv.style.display = "none";
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" style="display: block;"></div>
```